# Find points using spatial polygons (boundaries)

Tags: php, mysql, polygon

I want to select photo based on location (lat/lon) when someone else searches by country or city.
For example, a photo's location is 12.127, 42.127 -> request is "San Francisco" -> select points inside this area (a good example is Instagram where a photo is linked to both city + country).

Right now I am looking to use polygons to find locations based on city/country. However, I am not sure how to use and store polygons in my database.

Here are my visual steps (not sure if that's right technically)

1. Get polygons/areas based on city/country from `table1`
2. Find points from `table2` inside the polygon from `table1`

If these steps are correct, I couldn't find any resources to get polygons for cities or countries.

Please include some examples + table structures and explanations on how to implement this.

Comment: it sounds not like something you'd like to solve using SQL. 
can you use Google Maps API? Read up on "Geocoding"?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResults

Comment: @yuan3y I was thinking about using 'radius' function, however this won't be accurate because actual boundaries can vary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql for quite some time has been supporting [geospatial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html) data types and functions.

You can store a city or any other place as a polygon and you can use one of the [Within() or Contains()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-function-reference.html) functions (there are 3 of each) to test if a point is within a city.

Mysql documentation contains a great deal of examples on the data types and functions. You can also find both free and not free sources on the Internet that contain the coordinates of various metro areas. Recommending offsite resource is off topic on SO, so I will not be making any recommendations.